# Prevent slide out behavior of Sidebar in NavigationSplitView

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationsplitview

I have a navigationSplitView on an iPad.  The detail view contains a pdfView (representable) with page style (pdfView.usePageViewController(true)).  I have a button to control visibility of the sidebar.

Unfortunately the default slide out behavior of the sidebar is interfering with my backwards paging.  Is there anyway to disable the swipe to slide out feature of the sidebar for the navigationSplitView?

I have a columnVisibility argument for my navigationSplitView and initially set it's value to .all

In the example below, with any multi page pdf, when you swipe to end and then back again it keeps pulling out the navigation sidebar rather than paging.  Behavior is inconsistent so after trying several times the behavior should be apparent.

```
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit

enum Detail: Hashable {
    case pdfView
    case anotherView
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selection: Detail?
    @State private var columnVisibility = NavigationSplitViewVisibility.all
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                Section {
                    NavigationLink(value: Detail.pdfView) {
                        HStack(spacing: 12) {
                            Image(systemName: "scroll")
                            Text("PDF View")
                        }
                    }
                    NavigationLink(value: Detail.anotherView) {
                        HStack(spacing: 12) {
                            Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                            Text("Another View")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            if selection == .pdfView {
                if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "example", withExtension: "pdf") {
                    PDFKitView(url: url)
                } else {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            } else {
                Text("Another View")
            }
            
        }
        .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)
    }
}

struct PDFKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let url: URL
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitView>) -> PDFKitView.UIViewType {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: self.url)
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true)
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitView>) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "interfering with my horizontalScrollView"? How does it interfere? Can you show a [mcve].

Comment: I thought I would be able to create a minimal reproducible example but it's proving a bit challenging.  It made me realize though that maybe my question should have been for a paged view rather than scrollView.  I have a representable PDFView and using page style to display the pdf pages.  Then I swipe to scroll back with sidebar hidden it keeps bringing up the sidebar rather than paging back.  I'll try to create an example.

Comment: I've updated the question to more accurately reflect my use case and will try to create an example.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for your comment.  I added an example that shows the issue I'm having.